# $18x\equiv1\pmod{ 25}$. Computing inverses modulo a square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I just got started with discrete math and modular arithmetic and I'm trying to get good at modular congruences. I was trying to solve this exercise:

$$18x\equiv1\bmod {25}$$

Here's what I've tried:

$$18x\equiv1\text{ }(25) \iff 18x \equiv 26\text{ } (25) \mathop{\iff}^{\text{div by 2}} 9x \equiv 13\text{ }(25)\iff 9x \equiv -1\text{ }(25)$$

Then I'm not quite sure how to proceed. This is the first exercise of this kind I'm attempting, and for a bit I thought I was onto something.

What am I missing?

Comment: It is not true that $9x\equiv 13\implies 9x\equiv -1$.  After all, $13\not \equiv -1\pmod {25}$.

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote it.

Comment: formatting tip: `$\pmod{25}$` produces $\pmod{25}$

Comment: Got it, thank you man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the Euclidean algorithm to find $\gcd(18,25)$:

$$25=18\times 1+7$$
$$18=7\times 2+4$$
$$7=4\times 1+3$$
$$4=3\times 1+1$$

which, backwards, gives you:

$$\begin{array}{rl}1&=4\times1+3\times(-1)\\&=4\times 1+(7\times 1+4\times (-1))\times (-1)\\&=7\times(-1)+4\times 2\\&=7\times(-1)+(18\times 1+7\times(-2))\times 2\\&=18\times 2+7\times (-5)\\&=18\times 2+(25\times 1+18\times(-1))\times(-5)\\&=25\times(-5)+18\times 7\end{array}$$

The point of this calculation was to express $1=\gcd(25, 18)$ in the form $25a+18b$ with $a, b$-integers.

Once you have that, you will see that the factor multiplying $18$ (in this case, $7$) acts as an inverse of $18\pmod{25}$. In particular, $7\times 18\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, and also, if $18x\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, by multiplying by $7$ you get $7\times 18x\equiv 7\pmod{25}$, i.e. $x\equiv 7\pmod{25}$.

Comment: "Once you have that, you will see that the factor multiplying $18$ (in this case, $7$) acts as an inverse of $18 \pmod{25}$" --- is this always the case? Can it realiably be used as a method to solve this kind of equations?

Comment: @SamueleB. Yes, and the reason is clear the from the last equality ($1=25\times(-5)+18\times 7$). Namely, $18\times 7\equiv 1\pmod{25}$ because the difference between those two numbers is $25\times(-5)$ - divisible by $25$. The same will happen in the general case. Note the crucial bit here overall is that $\gcd(18, 25)=1$ - without that, $\text{anything}\times18$ would be divisible by the same $\gcd$ ($\pmod{25}$ or not) and won't be able to be $1$.

Comment: @SamueleB. Worth strong emphasis: this *back*-substitution method is the worst way to perform the extended Euclidean algorithm by hand since it is notoriously error prone. Better to use the *forward* version described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242) and its links, or its [fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242).

Answer (score 4):

$$18x\equiv 1\pmod{25} \\ -7x\equiv1\pmod{25} \\ 7x\equiv-1\pmod{25}\\7x\equiv49\pmod{25} \\ \therefore x\equiv 7\pmod{25}$$

Comment: I think it’s relevant to say why the cancellation law is valid.

Comment: Well just because 7 and 25 are relative prime

Comment: I would be helpful to explain any *general* ideas used above, i.e. is the method ad-hoc and works only for this case or does it work more generally? We can't infer that from what little is written in the answer. Lacking such the OP likely won't know how to use the above to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should have mentioned your reduction is valid because $2$ is coprime to $25$, hence a unit mod. $25$. There remains to find the inverse of $9\bmod 25$. This inverse is deduced from a Bézout's relation between $9$ and $25$.

However, it is as simple to determine directly the inverse of $18$. Even if there is no obvious Bézout's relation, you have at your disposal the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Here is how it goes:

\begin{array}{rrrr}
r_i&u_i&v_i&q_i \\ \hline
25&0&1  \\
18&1&0&1\\ \hline
7&-1&1&2 \\ 
4&3&-2 & 1 \\
3&-4&3&1 \\
1&7&-5 \\ \hline
\end{array}
Therefore, a Bézout's relation is $\;7\cdot 18-5\cdot 25=1$, the inverse of $18\bmod 25=7$, i.e. the solution is
$$18 x\equiv 1\iff x\equiv 7\cdot 1=7\mod 25.$$

*Some explanations*:

The extended Euclidean theorem asserts that  *all* remainders in the classical Euclidean algorithm are linear combinations of the two given numbers.

Indeed,  at the $i$-th step, denote $r_i, q_i$ the remainder and the quotient, and $u_i, v_i$ the coefficients of the linear combination for $r_i$. A close examination of the classical Euclidean algorithm  yields a recursive relation for the coefficients $u_i,v_i$ (here, $25$ and $18$ are considered as $r_{-1}$ and $r_0$ respectiively).:
$$u_{i+1}=u_{i-1}-q_iu_i,\qquad v_{i+1}=v_{i-1}-q_iv_i $$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: You're right. I've added a link to the Wikipedia notice, and a short explanation of the notations and the recursive relation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$9x\equiv13\pmod{25}$ means $9x\equiv13+2\times25=63\pmod{25}$

(and, as pointed out in comments, $9x\equiv13\pmod{25}$ does not mean $9x\equiv-1\pmod{25}$).

Comment: So a good way to go about finding numbers to sub into the equation is to take the number I want to sub out and find multiples of the modulo plus that number, correct? And if possible, I can choose one that allows me to divide the whole equation by a common factor.

Comment: I think that way works well for small numbers, as in this problem.  More generally, you may want to use the extended Euclidean algorithm to get a Bezout identity (as some of the other answers have discussed)

Comment: @SamueleB. division isn't always defined well in modular arithmetic. or it get hard to do or tedious. Division only gets defined  easily when two values have no common factors at least mostly. If they share their radical in common with the modulus have fun ...  Also try using division by 2 for  $1048576x \equiv 23 \pmod {25}$  it'll be time consuming as there are 20 factors of 2 in the former. and you'll get at most 4 per negation in the later.

Comment: @SamueleB. It is indeed a good way. Is a special case of [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) where we compute the exact multiple of the modulus needed to add to the numerator in order to make the quotient exact.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way:** $ $ lift inverse $\!\bmod 5\!:\ \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{a'} \equiv {\large \frac{1}{18}\equiv \frac{6}3}\equiv \color{#0a0}2}^{\!\!\!\textstyle\Rightarrow\, 18\cdot \color{#0a0}2 = \color{#0a0}{1\! +\! 7\cdot 5}}\,$ up to $\!\bmod 5^2$ as follows
$\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}{5^{\large 2}}\!: \dfrac{1}{18}\!\equiv\!\dfrac{\color{#0a0}2}{18\!\cdot\!\color{#0a0}2} \!\equiv\! \dfrac{\color{#0a0}2}{\color{#0a0}{1\!+\!7\cdot 5}}\equiv\,\overbrace{2(1\!-\!7\cdot 5)}^{\large \equiv \ 7},\, $ by $\ \color{#c00}{5^{\large 2}\!\equiv 0}.\,$ **Generally** if $\,{\overbrace{1/a\equiv a'\pmod{\!n}}^{\!\!\textstyle\Rightarrow\ a\color{#0a0}{a' = 1+j\,n}}}\,$

$\!\!\bmod \color{#c00}{n^2}\!:\ \dfrac{1}{a}\,\equiv\,\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{a'}}{a\color{#0a0}{a'}}\!\equiv \dfrac{\color{#0a0}{a'}}{\color{#0a0}{1+j\,n}}\equiv\, a'(1-j\,n),\ $ by $\ \color{#c00}{n^2\equiv 0},\,$ lifts inverse $\!\bmod n\,$ up to $\!\bmod{n^2}$

because, $ $ we have that: $\ (\color{#0a0}{1+j\,n})\,(1-j\,n)\:\! =\:\! 1-j^2\color{#c00}{n^2}\equiv 1,\, $ so $\ (\color{#0a0}{1+j\,n})^{-1}\equiv 1-j\,n$.

This can [be viewed as](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3316432/242) using Hensel lifting (Newton's method) to compute inverses. 
 In general, as above, [it is trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3225783/242) to invert a unit + nilpotent by using a (terminating) [geometric series,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160482/242) which is a special case of the general [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242).

Of course we can also use general inversion methods $\!\bmod n^2,\,$ but usually they will be less efficient. There are a few worked examples using a handful of such methods (including all those in the other answers) presented  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242). This includes most all the common known methods (and their optimizations).

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13190/242) for another example computed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). This identity is crucial for handling multiplicative inverses in  $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$. E.g.,

**invertible elements**
$a \in \mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ has inverse $x$ iff there is some integer $k $ such that $ax = kn + 1$ iff (by Bézout's identity) $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime. This means that one should be careful when dividing  in $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$ : you can divide by $b$ iff $b$ is relatively prime to $n$.

In a concrete situation like yours, you can find the inverse of $a$ using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/euclidean.html#extendedeuclidean).

Answer (score 0):

You can procede (**from your false conclusion**) like this: $$9x\equiv 24 \pmod {25}\implies 3x\equiv 8 \pmod {25} $$

$$\implies 3x\equiv 33 \pmod {25} \implies \boxed{x\equiv 11 \pmod {25} }$$

---

Now the **correct** result is: $$9x\equiv 13 \pmod {25}\implies 9x\equiv -12 \pmod {25} $$

$$\implies 3x\equiv -4 \pmod {25} \implies 3x\equiv 21 \pmod {25} \implies\boxed{x\equiv 7 \pmod {25} }$$

Comment: I didn't downvote, but why would you proceed from a false conclusion??

Comment: What is the difference, he just want to see how to procede?

Comment: Mind blowing...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I find it mind blowing that you would show me how to proceed without pointing out my error. "What is the difference," well the difference is I'm trying to learn, and learning also means becoming better at not making mistakes, not more efficient at proceeding through an exercise after I've made a mistake.

Comment: My comments on Isaac's answer also apply here (I did not downvote).